# In ActivityPub, how do you get an inbox URL?

Tags: activitypub, webfinger

I know that servers communicate by POSTing to an inbox and outbox. But what's the URL for the inbox and outbox?

Answer (score 9):

## How to get the inbox or outbox URL

The URL is whatever the implementing server says it is. So it's different for each [ActivityPub](https://www.w3.org/TR/activitypub) server.

The inbox and outbox URL for an actor is defined *in* the JSON-LD document for an actor:

```
{ 
  "@context": ["https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams",
               {"@language": "ja"}],
  "type": "Person",
  "id": "https://kenzoishii.example.com/",
  
  // Right here!
  "inbox": "https://kenzoishii.example.com/inbox.json",
  "outbox": "https://kenzoishii.example.com/feed.json",

  ...
}
```

This also means that the inbox and outbox can be *actor-specific*, not just server specific.

## How to get the actor JSON

Some ActivityPub sites [like Mastodon](https://blog.joinmastodon.org/2018/06/how-to-implement-a-basic-activitypub-server/) make use of [Webfinger](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7033) to standardize a URL that can be used to get an actor's JSON-LD doc:

```
/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:foo@example.org
```

In this case, if you wanted to know the inbox for `flaque@mastodon.social`, you would first [query](https://mastodon.technology/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:flaque@mastodon.technology) the webfinger:

```
GET https://mastodon.technology/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:flaque@mastodon.technology
```

That would give you a JSON object like this:

```
{
  subject: "acct:Flaque@mastodon.technology",
  links: [
    {
      rel: "self",
      type: "application/activity+json",
      href: "https://mastodon.technology/users/Flaque"
    }
  ]
}
```

With that `href: https://mastodon.technology/users/Flaque`, you can get the JSON representation with:

```
https://mastodon.technology/users/Flaque.json
```

(Note the `.json`!)

That would then give you a full actor object, which would include the `inbox` and `outbox`:

```
{
  "inbox": "https://mastodon.technology/users/Flaque/inbox",
  "outbox": "https://mastodon.technology/users/Flaque/outbox",
  ...
}
```

Comment: To get the inbox/outbox queue for an actor you must sen a GET request with an Accept header value of "application/ld+json; profile="https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams". It's better (because in the ActivityPub spec) than adding the .json extension to the URL.

Comment: I 100% agree that calling the URL as given in the webfinger response should be the correct way to get the actor json, but for my user it doesn't work. Only adding .json (hate doing this) seems to work: [curl  -H 'Accept: application/ld+json; profile="https://w3.org/ns/activitystreams"' https://mastodon.social/users/haentz] does not show the json data…